# Convert dataframe data from columns to rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

In Pandas, I'm trying to relocate data placed in several columns, to several rows in the sense suggested by the two tables below.

[image: Example]

Each customer should appear in as many rows as they made purchases. If it matters, column `j+1` can only have a value if column `j` does too.

How do I go about this?

Comment: Try to share data and not images.

Comment: This is called [**converting from wide-form to long-form**](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+long+form+wide+form) (or "melting"). There are many duplicates already, please pick one of those 49 hits and close-as-duplicate.

Comment: @smci Thank you very much for the terminology. That's useful. I will do as you suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas offers something specifically meant for this called `melt`: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html

Without a sample of your code I can't give an example that is code specific, but you would have something like this:

```
id_vars = ['Customer']
var_name = 'Purchase Type'
value_name = 'Value'

melted_df = pf.melt(unmelted_df, id_vars=id_vars, var_name=var_name, value_name=value_name)
```

As a result, you would get a melted `DataFrame` where `Purchase 1`, `Purchase 2`, etc are attributes of 'Purchase Type' and the value of those original purchases is displayed in `Value`.

Comment: This was enough. Thank you very much.